# How does one access analytical views using odata?

Tags: hana

I have an analytical view and an .xsodata to expose it to web. The question is how is the access url formed? HANA documentation is insufficient here, and the same for the moderated SCN.

Here is my func_x_cview.xsodata:

```
service namespace "CTag" {
    "MyPackage::FUNC_X_CALC_VIEW" as "CView" keys generate local "ID"
    parameters via entity "InputParams" ; 
}
```

`http://awshana:8000/package/path/to/xsodata/file/$metadata` shows:

```
<EntityType Name="InputParamsType">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="ATTRIBUTE"/>
        <PropertyRef Name="ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"/>
        <PropertyRef Name="category"/>
        <PropertyRef Name="from_date"/>
        <PropertyRef Name="process"/>
        <PropertyRef Name="to_date"/>
    </Key>
    <Property Name="ATTRIBUTE" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="50"/>
    <Property Name="ATTRIBUTE_VALUE" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="100"/>
    <Property Name="category" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="50"/>
    <Property Name="from_date" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false"/>
    <Property Name="process" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="50"/>
    <Property Name="to_date" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false"/>
    <NavigationProperty Name="Results" Relationship="CTag.InputParams_CViewType"
                    FromRole="InputParamsPrincipal"
                    ToRole="CViewDependent"/>
</EntityType>
```

What should be the access url? Does the xsodata need any tweaking?

Thanks

--EDIT--

When trying url like suggested by ongis-nade to  `http://awshana:8000/Pkg/Proj_X/services/tagA.xsodata/InputParams%28%27category%27=%27abcd%27%29/Results?$select=exception_name` then I get an error like the following:

```
<error>
  <code/>
  <message xml:lang="en-US">
     No property ''category'' exists in type 'CTag.InputParamsType'.
  </message>
</error>
```

This is confusing as we can see a property named `category` in the entity named `InputParamsType` in the `$metadata` query.

Removing the single quotes around `category` (also tried double-quoting) gives
`http://awshana:8000/Pkg/Proj_X/services/tagA.xsodata/InputParams%28category=%27abcd%27%29/Results?$select=exception_name`

```
<error>
  <code/>
  <message xml:lang="en-US">
     The number of keys specified in the URI at position 27 does not match number of key properties for the resource 'CTag.InputParamsType'.
  </message>
</error>
```

So a single quote is needed.

A step closer but still the same question. Do I need to qualify each parameter name somehow?

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't put tag information in your title. The tagging system here is very good at classifying things, and doesn't need help. :-) Please see [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/172661). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the URL will be formed as:

```
http://awshana:8000/Pkg/Proj_X/services/tagA.xsodata/InputParams(category='abcd')/Results?
```

The "InputParams" name is of course reflected in your service definition

I also found a good example here: http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/hana/blog/2013/01/22/rest-your-models-on-sap-hana-xs

Comment: I still get an error with this url. I have edited the post above.

Answer (score 2):

May be a bit late: But you have to specify a value for each key parameter.
Note also, that timestamps must be specified in ODatas Edm.DateTime format.

Example for your service:

```
        http://server:8080/pathToService/tagA.xsodata/InputParams(ATTRIBUTE='?',ATTRIBUTE_VALUE='?',category='?',from_date=datetime'2014-01-01T00:00:00',process='?',to_date=datetime'2014-09-01T00:00:00')/Results
```